# What program does apple uses to create modular javascript files

Tags: javascript, module, documentation

When I looked at the new MacBook website from Apple I saw a nice smooth scrolling effect on the wireless page. I started digging in the JavaScript and found an uncompressed JavaScript file and I was blown away. (https://www.apple.com/v/macbook/a/scripts/wireless.built.js)

There were so many comments, and you could almost follow what they were thinking when they created this script. I tried to create a JavaScript file like this on my own, but in less than 5 minutes I figured out that it was almost impossible to keep it nice looking and understandable. So my question is: What program does Apple use to create this kind of JavaScript files? It is not a default code editor, but a program that supports built file. There are some good ones out there, but they all have libraries you have to follow, this one is just plain JavaScript and nothing more.

Comment: Take a look at [JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/). JSDoc is an automatic documentation generator for JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no tool to magically make your code look nice.

Apple has a strict code style guide that requires all developers to show discipline when writing code, or their code will be rejected from entering their repo.

It's nothing special really, just proper developer discipline.

Comment: I think I asked wrong, is there a program to work easily with modules?

Comment: Have a look at jspm, webpack, requirejs, and commonjs